# Open Office and subversion compatibility

Tags: svn, openoffice.org, tortoisesvn

Does anyone have any experience placing OpenOffice documents under source control using Subversion? In particular, does Subversion merge documents correctly/efficiently etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [this project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oosvn/), an extension to openoffice that allows you to handle subversion stuff inside OpenOffice. Yet, it seems a little outdated :(

On the other hand, you have the [odfsvn project](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/OOoSVN) that provides tools to handle OpenOffice document in subversion (but seems limited to Mac and Linux systems)

And last but not least, the [tortoiseSVN scripts](http://blog.raz-l.com/2010/01/comparing-openoffice-documents-versions.html) to retrieve OpenOffice diffs.

Answer (score 3):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) has diff and merge scripts for ODT and ODS, so they could potentially be merged. That depends on OpenOffice's capabilities in that regard, though.

Basically, those scripts call a helper program to do the comparison as all that SVN sees is a binary blob. The helper program in that case is simply a scripting interface to OpenOffice.

Just look in your TortoiseSVN\Diff-Scripts folder to find them. They are invoked automatically if yout try comparing or merging one of the supported files.

Comment: For whatever reason, the .vbs files to compare ODS and ODT were missing on my TortoiseSVN installation (though other scripts like for DOCX were ok). I grabbed files from https://github.com/jrk/tortoisegit/tree/3943dc12e10fe923998e3367f83d9b8e709eb271/contrib/other/diff-scripts , added them to diff-scripts folder and it worked !