# How to compare open office .ods files in SVN

Tags: svn, openoffice.org, ods

I am unable to compare the local ods file with the remote ods file in SVN. Is their any way to do this?

Comment: `.ods` are archives, so binary files.

Comment: ya, any alternate ways??

Comment: I made the title more specific and hope to save it from being closed. It's a good question IMHO.

Comment: but que is closed..!!!

Comment: It might be reopened. Needs some more votes ...

Comment: For whatever reason, the .vbs files to compare ODS and ODT were missing on my TortoiseSVN installation (though other scripts like for DOCX were ok). I grabbed files from https://github.com/jrk/tortoisegit/tree/3943dc12e10fe923998e3367f83d9b8e709eb271/contrib/other/diff-scripts , added them to diff-scripts folder and it worked !

Answer (score 3):

Subversion cannot natively diff binary files. Open Office has a [compare documents](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Comparing_documents) feature; if you can script into that, you can tell Subversion to use that as your `diff-cmd` TortoiseSVN ships with a set of scripts that do this for both MS Word and Open Office files, so if you're on Windows there's not much left to do.

Otherwise, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057055/open-office-and-subversion-compatibility) and [here](https://stmllr.net/blog/creating-a-diff-of-openoffice-odt-documents-on-the-command-line/)

Comment: The last link should be https://stmllr.net/blog/creating-a-diff-of-openoffice-odt-documents-on-the-command-line/ (and I can't edit, I get a "queue is full" error for an hour)